Define macro to another macro : a hack to re-declare constexpr variable
I want to ease coding a very complex function with re-declarable variable hack.
It can be very useful for constexpr assignment later.
Here is MCVE ::-
int main(){/// line 1

    #define MY_CONCAT_INTERNAL(x, y) x ## y
    #define MY_CONCAT(x, y) MY_CONCAT_INTERNAL(x, y)
    #define R MY_CONCAT(r,__LINE__)

    constexpr int R =5;   //<== user code 1  (line 7)

    #define R_PREV R 
    #define R MY_CONCAT(r,__LINE__)

    constexpr int R=R_PREV+1;   //<== user code 2  (line 12)
}

I expect the above to be expanded to ::-
    constexpr int r_unique7 = 5;
    constexpr int r_unique12 = r_unique7+1;

However, R_PREV in user code 2 line expands to R, and thus, the whole line expands to
    constexpr int r_unique12 = r_unique12+1;

How to make R_PREV = the previous R correctly ?
Realized that it is a bad practice, I will use it only for 1 function. I promise.

Can't be done, macros don't work like that.

Stateful metaprogramming can do this without any macros: https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr-cpp20 But as it's very complex, it's probably an overkill in this case.

@HolyBlackCat :: What? How? It is a super amazing holy link.  Thanks, HolyBlackCat.

Note that stateful metaprograming is meant to be ill-formed by the standard even if no current wording mandates so. Use it at your own risk.

@Weijun Zhou :: I agree. Thanks.

@HolyBlackCat :: If you post as an answer, I will upvote it.

Just linking the library doesn't deserve a full answer, IMO.

@HolyBlackCat :: ....  and copy code from this link .... if you wish .... https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/noo4dTs7c   (still don't know why not work with Visual C++ in godbolt , but work in Visual C++ in my computer)
